# MongoDB Unique Index Creation

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I would like to create a unique index on a field in my MongoDB database. I know that I could enforce it through my application, but I would like to also enforce it on the MongoDB database as well!

I'm looking at the following documentation:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-index/

What I do not get is that who is running the following bit of code?

```
db.records.createIndex( { userid: 1 } )
```

What is the db object in this case? Is there any initialisation script that I could consider so that I can pre-populate my collections if they do not exist, apply indexes if they do not exist? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impractical to enforce a unique key constraint in your application - just start thinking through how you would do that...

The article you are reading is showing mongo shell commands. With mongo installed, open a shell, type `mongo` and you will see the mongo prompt. This is a full javascript execution environment (based on V8) so you can do most anything here that you can in javascript.

The `db` part of the command refers to the mongo database your are currently using. When you start the mongo shell, you are automatically connected to the test database. When you `use records` in the shell, you are changing databases.

Usually, I find it easier to write scripts that I push to the mongo shell: replaying multi-line commands is tedious in the shell. Here is your example.

```
// Example collection initialization script
// USE:
//   mongo < thisFile

// connect to mongo test database
use test

// create a unique index on records
// will create collection if it does not already exist
db.records.createIndex({userId:1}, {unique:true})

// insert some test data
db.records.insert({userId:1, name:'bob'})
db.records.insert({userId:2, name:'nancy'})

// unique does not mean the field must exist in the inserted doc
db.records.insert({name:'no userId is OK'})
// but there can be only one doc without a userId
db.records.insert({name:'ohhh nooo'})

// display indexes
db.records.getIndexes()

// drop the collection so we can test the initialization script
//db.records.drop()
```

Comment: Ok! Thanks! That gives me a starting point to create a script like this that I could run upon my application start! Thanks again!